# How to force raster algebra to save result in named file

Tags: r, raster

When working with large raster* objects, it is useful to work with rasters that are stored on disk rather than in memory. For example, if we use `calc`, there is an option to provide a filename in which the result is stored. E.g.

```
library(raster)
a1 = array(rep(1:12, each = 9), dim = c(3,3,12))
b1 = brick(a1)
res1 = calc(b1, mean, 'xyz_test1.nc')
inMemory(res1)
#FALSE
```

However, `calc` only operates on a single raster* object. Is there a way to achieve the same thing when using functions that operate on more than one raster* object, such as arithmetic operators?

```
a2 = array(rep(1:4, each = 3*9) + rnorm(4*3*9), dim = c(3,3,12))
b2 = brick(a2)
res2 = b1 / b2
inMemory(res2)
#TRUE
```

According to `help("Arith-methods")`, "If the values of the output Raster* cannot be held in memory, they will be saved to a temporary file". But what if the output *can* fit in memory but you want it stored on disk (preferably in a named file) to save memory for subsequent operations? Is there a way to force this, (short of using `writeRaster(x, filename); remove(x); x <- brick(filename)` after every calculation)?

Comment: As a hack, you could perhaps make [`canProcessInMemory` to return FALSE](https://github.com/cran/raster/blob/master/R/arith.R#L38) and then revert back to normal operation after you've made your calculation.

Comment: Thanks @RomanLuštrik - I've actually started doing something similar. Setting `rasterOptions(maxmemory = ...)` to a small value at start of operation, then restoring it afterwards. This effectively achieves what you suggested with `canProcessInMemory`. Its a bit of a hack but unless there's a better solution which allows to specify the raster file it will get me by :-)

Comment: That was my initial thought, but then opted to report on the canProcessInMemory function... :)